# Error when using Jenkins but not Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, cucumber

I am using Jenkins to launch Cucumber (using Maven) acceptance tests.
When I run my tests in Eclipse, everything goes well but, when I launch them with Jenkins, I have a java.lang.AssertionError: null for a method call.

I just don't know what is the problem because I have this error with only one method...

If you have any idea, I would be glad to hear it !
Thank you

Comment: stack trace may be useful

Comment: also code of failing test

Answer (score 0):

After logging in and logging out, found out that there was no more problem... I don't know how to explain it !

Thank you all of you for your interest !